# I have this error when i try to get the admin page in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

im new with symfony2, i installed FOSuserbundle , i did the configuration of security.yml and routing, create the user entity,but when i tape:http://localhost/PhpProject1/web/app_dev.php,i get this error :
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 309:
Unrecognized option "fos_user" under "swiftmailer.mailers.default"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong syntax in your `app/config/config.yml`.

Each bundle alias must be at the same level of indentation, e.g. :

```
swiftmailer:
    # options

fos_user:
    # options
```

Currently, you have something like :

```
swiftmailer:
    # options
    fos_user:
        # options
```